# How to farm large amount of studs in Lego Star Wars The Force Awakens

Tags: ps4, lego-star-wars-the-force-awakens

I have been playing through Lego Star Wars: The Force Awakens

Once you get to the end of the game most of the characters are unlocked but you need to actually "buy" them in order to use them in free play.

The problem is several characters, the most famous ones in particular, can cost multiples of all the studs collected throughout the whole game.

Where is a good place to farm considerable amounts of studs quickly in this game?

What are good strategies to speed up studs collection at the game end, or throughout the game itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Lego Star Wars: The Force Awakens is concerned i found the Dejarik Battle Minigame on board of the Millenium Falcon very effective. Even without red brick studs multipliers (more on this later) you should get about half a million studs each run and that takes like just a few minutes to complete.

As for strategies: find, buy and activate red brick with stud multiplier bonus as soon as possible in the game.